# Prevent body scrolling when Overlay is shown in AMP

Tags: css, amp-html, google-amp

Is there any way I can disable scroll on `<body>` in AMP when an overlay is shown?

This is what I've tried:

```css
.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.overlay.show {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.taptoclose {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  padding 30px;
  color: #000;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp>
<head>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body [class]="noscrollBody ? 'noscroll' : ''" on="tap:AMP.setState({
    showOverlay: true,
    noscrollBody: true
  })">

<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>
<h4>Dummy data to show scroll. Tap anywhere to show Overlay.</h4>

<div class="overlay" [class]="showOverlay ? 'overlay show' : 'overlay'" on="tap:AMP.setState({
    showOverlay: false,
    noscrollBody: false
  })">
</div>
</body>
```

However, following is visible in console which means AMP is forcing to always show `overflow` for `<html>` and `<body>`

```
html.i-amphtml-singledoc>body {
    overflow: visible!important;
    position: relative!important;
}
```

I've looked into [documentation and HTML Specs of AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec) but unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use amp-lightbox (https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-lightbox/) to create an overlay that disables scrolling the background. This could be a good option if there's not a reason you've avoided using it.

Comment: often it's not an option since you need some other elements be active outside of overlay. Like navbar or header